# How to connect PHP to MySQL using mysqli and SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mysqli

I have a connection between PHP and MySQL that works well, but I would like to secure it with SSL (Remote server)

My working connection code is as follows (Without SSL parameters):

```
    <?php// mysql creditentials
define('DB_HOST', $ip);
define('DB_USER', $user);
define('DB_PASS', $pass);
define('DB_NAME', $db);
define('DB_PORT', $port);

$con = @new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error connecting to MySQL : (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error . "\n";
}
else {
    $mysql_status = 'Connected to MySQL on ' . $con->host_info . "\n";
}

$con->set_charset('utf8');

?>
```

I found several examples, including :

```
mysqli_ssl_set($con,"C:/mysqlCerts/client-key.pem","C:/mysqlCerts/client-cert.pem","C:/mysqlCerts/ca-cert.pem",NULL,NULL);
```

Also :

```html
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$con = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($con, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$con->ssl_set('C:/mysqlCerts/client-key.pem', 'C:/mysqlCerts/client-cert.pem', 'C:/mysqlCerts/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect($con, $host, $user, $pass, $db_name, 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
if (!$link) {
    die('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
}
else {
    $res = $con->query('SHOW TABLES;');
    print_r($res);
    $con->close();
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work.

I got the following warning :

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

What am i doing wrong ? My certificates work, correctly installed, the connection works with my MySQL client (Webyog SQLyog)

How can I change this code for the SSL connection to work?

I hope that the question is not duplicated, if it is the case thank you to indicate me the page that I missed ...

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Why silence the warnings? You echo them out on the line anyway.